Why local variable is not assigned to a non-local variable with the same name?
Scenario:
$ cat t426.sh
set -x
f()
{
    local x="x"
    eval $1=$x
}

x="y"

f x

echo $x

$ bash t426.sh
+ x=y
+ f x
+ local x=x
+ eval x=x
++ x=x
+ echo y
y

Here we see that y is printed. I expect that x is printed.
If I change the name of the local variable from x to x_, then x is printed.
Why local variable is not assigned to a non-local variable with the same name?
How to fix, so that local variable has the same name as a non-local variable?

How would you recognise which variable (local versus global) is used? Local variables mask global ones.

You've defined a local variables named x. Why would eval assign to the global variable of the same name? Just because the value of $1 is x doesn't mean $1 refers to the global variable. The argument is just a string, not some kind of reference.

f behaves just as if its definition where f () { local x="x"; x=x; }.

what's the main objective? have the function redefine the value of a global variable?

@markp-fuso Objective: in this case: function redefine the value of a global variable; in general case: separate return code of a function (e.g. status of an operation: OK/NOK) from the actual result (valid if status is OK) of the function.

@chepner @choroba Indeed, in this case eval assigns to the local variable. Thanks.

@pmor a nameref would handle redefining the value of a global variable (see my answer for one example); as for separate return codes ... I'm not quite following/understanding what you want ... are you talking about f() executing different commands (the command name is passed to f())? for the second requirement (return codes) I'd recommend asking a separate question, making sure to provide some examples of what you're trying to accomplish

local means local. It's a feature, not a bug (-;

See BashFAQ/006 (How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?) and Indirect variable assignment in bash.

@markp-fuso Re: "what you want": function returns success/failure codes -- returning any other data via "result" parameters. See 1, 2, 3.

You're making it more complicated with eval, that's just taking text and turning it into a name for the variable assignment.  When you do local x from inside a function, you create a local variable named x.  From that point on until you exit the function, it is only using your local variable x.  That's actually the entire purpose of local variables -- that they are not global!  That means it cannot see or change the global variables.  If you want your variable in the function to modify the global x variable, just do x=1 without the local.  Bash variables are global by default.

Local variables are normally used so that functions never, ever, under any circumstance, touch a global variable.  This makes the functions completely self-contained and always safe to use in any context.  The moment the function loads, assign all your local variables, and only use those variables in your function.  Some languages only have local variables in functions, others let you choose.  But it's important to understand what they're actually about.  They are used to sandbox your function code to make it far less error-prone, and to make it easier to reuse or share your code.

@Raven Re: "If you want your variable in the function to modify the global x variable": no, I want function to modify a variable, which is passed to that function. Examples: f x (f modifies x), f y (f modifies y), etc.

You're not being clear about you actual goal. You say you want to run func x to modify x -- but do you mean modify local x or global x? Bash only passes in variables by string, there is no passing variables by reference. All variables are global by default. So x=4 in the function is global, while local x=4 is local to the function. If you're using eval to access a variable name, you're probably not approaching the problem in an ideal way. I've never needed to eval a variable in 25 years of Bash. I thought I needed to one time, but someone provided me with a better approach.

@Raven Re: "local x or global x": "function to modify a variable, which is passed to that function". In the example (in the question) local x isn't passed to that function, while global x is passed to that function. Hence, it is the global x, which is expected / needs to be modified by the function. Example: f x (f modifies global x).

@pmor: Then just set the variable, it is global by default.  There is almost never a time that eval is needed.  What is your actual goal overall (not to eval, but the goal)?

@Raven Re: "actual goal overall": to avoid possible variable name clashes. A user of function may not know which names are used inside the function, and still want the function to modify user passed variable with an arbitrary name.

Assumptions:

f() input is the name of a global variable
f() resets the value of the global variable (in this case always setting to the string 'x')

With bash 4.3+ we have access to the nameref feature which functions like a symlink to a (global) variable.
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash

f() {
    local -n _var=$1     # -n == nameref
    _var="x"
}

a=3
b="y"

echo "### before:"
typeset -p a b

f a
f b

echo "### after:"
typeset -p a b

Addressing OP's issue - local variable has the same name as a non-local variable - instead of a local variable with a constantly changing name (to match the global variable), you have a statically named local variable (_var) which acts as a symlink to the global variable.
Taking for a test drive:
$ ./myscript
### before:
declare -- a="3"
declare -- b="y"
### after:
declare -- a="x"
declare -- b="x"


As per your knowledge, is bash 4.3+ widely used in 2024? In other words: how likely in 2024 that nameref feature is not available?

@pmor 4.3 came out in ~2014; I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 which is currently running bash 5.1.16; I would expect all 'main stream' bash releases to include nameref support, but there could be outliers; an alternative to nameref would be indirect variable references ... doable/workable but a bit convoluted to use ... a web search should bring up plenty of hits on using indirect variable references

The big outlier is macOS, where the casual user is still using bash 3.2 unless they chose to use zsh or have installed a newer version of bash themselves. I don't know for sure, but I would agree that being stuck on a version older than 4.3 would be rather an exceptional case in 2024.

The -l option for declare is not "local", it is "lowercase".

Is it possible for a local variable to have the same name as a non-local variable, and still to update a non-local variable? Reason for the question: possible variable name clashes. A user of function may not know which names are used inside the function, and still want the function to modify user passed variable with an arbitrary name.

@pmor that's what the nameref provides; the function has no idea the name of the global variable (the name passed to the function); additionally defining the variable as 'local' insures no clashes with global variables with the same name

Issue: for f _var your code leads to local: warning: _var: circular name reference followed by warning: _var: circular name reference. How to fix? Bash version is 5.2.21.

@pmor I'm not aware of any easy fixes; pick a (local) name that you're 99.99% confident won't be passed to the function; there are some convoluted workarounds ... run a web search on linux nameref 'circular name reference' for some ideas

An alternate way to do this is to use the (ironic) -g "global" option to the local command.
f() {
  local -g "$1"="from function"
}

x="global scope"
declare -p x

f x
declare -p x

outputs
declare -- x="global scope"
declare -- x="from function"


Interesting approach. Consider a scenario when user creates function u with local variable x and calls function f (inside u) with argument x (local variable). The approach based on option -g will fail. Any ideas how to (correctly) handle such scenario? Note that user variable can have an arbitrary name.
